# Graphical visualisation of a big sparse matrix with 3D.js or Cairo

Tags: javascript, svg, visualization, cairo, bigdata

I designed [an *ad hoc* library to write SVG images](https://github.com/DyogenIBENS/LibsDyogen/blob/master/utils/mySvgDrawer.py). I use it for the graphical visualisation of large sparse matrices : homology matrices of the comparison of two genomes.

In my case, a usual homology matrix is 20 000 x 20 000 with around 30 000 scattered dots (representing homologies), for instance [this homology matrix](https://github.com/DyogenIBENS/PhylDiag/blob/0abdca5d447acd520cf0064b3b765b7d1719dede/res/WMH_Hs_Mm.svg).

My *ad hoc* library is not mature enough for new developpements and I am interested by the 3D.js library. I also found the graphical library Cairo and its binding pyCairo interesting.

My needs are :

- the possibility to output SVG, PNG or PDF images of the matrix.
- when the mouse get over a dot of the homology matrix I would like to show specific informations.
- a plus would be the ability to zoom in an area of the matrix, and show new details above a zoom threshold.

I know that 3D.js has dynamic features (interesting for navigating/zooming through the sparse matrix) but I wonder if it will display fast enough my data. It might be a better idea to use Cairo in an application and recompute the image for different zoom levels.

In brief I feel that I have 2 solutions :

- write a HTML file, with a 3D.js script that adds SVG elements of the homology matrix and interactivity. 3D.js would be great for sharing matrices from a server.
- write a dedicated app (e.g. with GTK) and draw the matrix inside the app with Cairo. Interactions would then be added by asking Cairo to re-draw each time the user interacts with the app.

Do I miss something ? Which solution would you use ?